# Running multiple kafka consumers inside express server

Tags: node.js, express, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am trying to build an express server that will receive http requests for potentially running multiple kafkajs consumers on demand (each consumer will listen to one particular topic only as each topic will have only one partition). I am trying to understand what limitations I might have with this setup if  my server ends up managing several consumers receiving messages at a time (to specify, the express app will essentially be used for running / disconnecting these consumers).
With my current knowledge I understand that using child processes / worker threads won't help me in scaling my application so I'm trying to get a better understanding of the restrictions involved.

Comment: Will you be running multiple web servers for high availability? If so, you'll need something else to track which server is running which consumer. Such as running the consumers separately from the express server, not as a child process

Comment: No. I will be running a single web server for the moment. My point of view here is to know what will be the limitations performance wise. Each consumer won't perform any heavy computational work but could receive a lot of messages to consume from Kafka. For additional context, this whole system (Kafka zookeeper, Kafka connect, web server, UI) will run in a separate docker container

Comment: In a docker compose environment for the moment.

Comment: What happens when the data is consumed? You update something in memory? If so, you might eventually reach out of memory exceptions and the web server could crash. Kafka connect can also run consumer/sink tasks on demand, and could persist data in a database that your express server would query and render to a UI

Comment: A consumer would consume messages from a topic and translate the value payload in a valid format for a redis cache and send it accordingly. I am using debezium Kafka connect distribution to listen to changes from a source database and update the cache when such events occur.

Comment: Redis kafka sink connector exists, so I'm wondering why kafkajs is necessary? I'm thinking there's scenario where managing too many consumers will cause the server to be slow to respond, but that would need benchmarked

Comment: I tried using the Redis kafka sink but for the debezium delete events, I couldn't get it working. In my case, I need to delete a corresponding db row in the cache when such event occurs.